# How to select all switch at time when click on one button in customized list view in android?

Tags: android, listview

I have a custom list view with the switch and I want to check all switch at a time when click on select all button.
after the lot of try , i did not find the solution how to select the all switch at a time in customized list view in android.

[image of custom list view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rcSv.png)

below is my adapter.

```
public class ViewHolder {
        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView textTitle;
        public Switch swApp;
    }

    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder") @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        Boolean state=false;

        ViewHolder viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

        convertView = mInflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.app_lock_list_item, parent, false);

            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

            viewHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ivAppIconAppLock);
            viewHolder.textTitle = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvAppLableAppLock);
            viewHolder.swApp = (Switch) convertView.findViewById(R.id.swAppLock);

            viewHolder.imageView.setImageDrawable(items.get(position).icon);
            viewHolder.textTitle.setText(items.get(position).name);

        //mDatabaseHelper.deleteLockApp();
        retriveData();
        Log.i("App",items.get(position).packageName);

            for(int j=0;j<lockPacName.size();j++)
            {
                if(items.get(position).packageName.equals(lockPacName.get(j)))
                {
                    state=true;
                }
            }

            viewHolder.swApp.setChecked(state);

        viewHolder.swApp
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(Switch view, boolean checked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        if (checked) {

                            LockAppDetail lockAppDetail = new LockAppDetail(
                                    items.get(position).packageName);

                            mDatabaseHelper.addPackageName(lockAppDetail);

                            Toast.makeText(context, "Insert...",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            mDatabaseHelper
                                    .deleteLockApp(items.get(position).packageName);

                            Toast.makeText(context, "Delete...",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                    }
                });

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: post some code that did you try.You dont expect from us to write your code right?

Comment: you show me how you select one switch, I'll show you how to select all of them :)

Comment: show some code that worked for you for selecting one

Comment: There is more than one issue (e.g. implementation of ViewHolder pattern) which needs to be fixed, but for the question you asked I'd suggest on button click to first add all relevant "packageName" items to the "lockPacName" object (looks like some kind of List, but your code still leaves much to guessing) and secondly to call "notifyDatasetChanged()" on your adapter. You'll get better answers on this site if your code sample is sufficient to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

you can define a global variable,when you select one ,set the value of the variable to be true,then refresh listview.

Comment: looks like a good idea if this global variable always will be checked in getView() before setting the state of the switch (viewHolder.swApp.setChecked(state); ) - could you add some code to clarify?